# Android Network traffic monitoring

Tags: android, android-networking, tcpdump

Is there a native android Api to monitor network traffic and may be restrict it ? I came across   TrafficStats but i dont think it provides a method to dump the packets and analyze it later or in real time. If there is no native support, then what are other possibilities to implement something like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used it myself, but have heard of others using a variant of `tcpdump` called `tcpdump-arm` for capturing and analyzing Android device traffic.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It seems good. let me look into this in detail.